# Filtering by BooleanProperty using NDB in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I have a boolean property in one of my model objects

```
class MyObject(ndb.Model)
    availability = ndb.BooleanProperty()
```

When I run a query, which searches for all objects whose `availability` is set to True. I see the following error

`TypeError: Cannot filter a non-Node argument; received BooleanProperty('availability')`

This is how I create my `query`

```
    query = cls.query()
    query.filter(cls.availability)
```

How do I query for `all the objects whose booleanproperty is set to true`

Comment: Shouldn't the filter be `query.filter(cls.availability == True)`?

Comment: Yup that fixed it. For some reason, I thought that == True was redundant. I guess in this case it is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query filter must also include the filtering operation for the property and the value(s) for the operation, none of which comes with a default:

```
query.filter(cls.availability == True)
```

From [Filtering by Property Values](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop):

> NDB supports these operations:
>
> ```
> property == value
> property < value
> property <= value
> property > value
> property >= value
> property != value
> property.IN([value1, value2])
> ```